# Kubernetes Azure OAuth2 with multiple hosts in one Nginx Ingress - CORS error

Tags: azure, nginx, oauth-2.0, cors

Im looking for the way to configure OAuth2 and Azure provider for Nginx Ingress with multiple hosts definitions.

I need add authentication over for my application dev.example.com on AKS which has internal auth based on Identity service.
I've read examples like this:
https://kristhecodingunicorn.com/post/k8s_nginx_oauth/#setting-up-authentication-with-oauth-20

I've created Application in Azure AD and configure it like described above:

> Redirect URIs - https://dev.example.com/oauth2/callback
>
> Front-channel logout - URL https://dev.example.com/oauth2/sign_out

As far I can see almost all works ok - when I open dev.example.com in browser it redirect me to MS Sign In form, then runs 2FA, and opens dev.example.com.
But there is one error during opening web site:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://api.dev.example.com/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration'
> from origin 'https://dev.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
> Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

the main application tries to connect to internal Identity service and gets an error because of CORS.

Is there a way to fix this?

here is my Nginx ingress for application:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://$host/oauth2/auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - dev.example.com
        - api.dev.example.com
      secretName: letsencrypt-cert
  rules:
    - host: dev.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: dev-service
                port:
                  number: 80
    - host: api.dev.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: api-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

and OAuth2 Configuration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --provider=oidc
        #- --provider=azure
        - --azure-tenant=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        - --skip-jwt-bearer-tokens=true
        - --skip-auth-preflight=true        
        - --email-domain=*
        - --http-address=0.0.0.0:4180
        - --cookie-domain=.example.com
        - --whitelist-domain=.example.com
        - --oidc-issuer-url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx/v2.0
        env:
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: client-id
              key: oauth2_proxy_client_id
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: client-secret
              key: oauth2_proxy_client_secret
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: cookie-secret
              key: oauth2_proxy_cookie_secret
        image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: oauth2-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4180
          protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: dev
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 4180
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4180
  selector:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: dev
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: dev.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /oauth2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: oauth2-proxy
            port:
              number: 4180
  - host: api.dev.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /oauth2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: oauth2-proxy
            port:
              number: 4180
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an SPA and API architecture here. Therefore you need to deal with CORS on the API side of things. As a first step you could implement CORS in your api-service, by plugging in a library.

A more elegant solution is to do so in the ingress, via a [CORS plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/cors/). This example is from Kong but maybe there is an equivalent plugin in NGINX. The approach is to build a custom ingress controller image and then add a  [configuration snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#main-snippet) to inject settings into the `nginx.conf` file, though it may prove difficult.

Be aware that in oauth2-proxy you are using a website security solution, which is unlikely to be SPA friendly during Ajax calls to APIs, eg when you need to refresh an expired access token. A backend for frontend (BFF) with a more complete design is preferred.